# Turn app.directive angular to typescript directive.ts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-cli, mean-stack

Please be indulgent, it's my first post.

I'm writing my first MEAN app and I'd like to use code I've already written.
I'd like to use custom angular.js including an app.directive function, and I'd like to know how to turn this function into a Typescript custom.directive.ts

Here's the custom drag function:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.run([function () { }]);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope){
  $scope.image = null;
  $scope.imageFileName = '';

  $scope.uploadme = {};
  $scope.uploadme.src = '';
}]);

app.directive('fileDropzone', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      file: '=',
      fileName: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var checkSize,
          isTypeValid,
          processDragOverOrEnter,
          validMimeTypes;

      processDragOverOrEnter = function (event) {
        if (event != null) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
        return false;
      };

      validMimeTypes = attrs.fileDropzone;

      checkSize = function(size) {
        var _ref;
        if (((_ref = attrs.maxFileSize) === (void 0) || _ref === '') || (size / 1024) / 1024 < attrs.maxFileSize) {
          return true;
        } else {
          alert("File must be smaller than " + attrs.maxFileSize + " MB");
          return false;
        }
      };

      isTypeValid = function(type) {
        if ((validMimeTypes === (void 0) || validMimeTypes === '') || validMimeTypes.indexOf(type) > -1) {
          return true;
        } else {
          alert("Invalid file type.  File must be one of following types " + validMimeTypes);
          return false;
        }
      };

      element.bind('dragover', processDragOverOrEnter);
      element.bind('dragenter', processDragOverOrEnter);

      return element.bind('drop', function(event) {
        var file, name, reader, size, type;
        if (event != null) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(evt) {
          if (checkSize(size) && isTypeValid(type)) {
            return scope.$apply(function() {
              scope.file = evt.target.result;
              if (angular.isString(scope.fileName)) {
                return scope.fileName = name;
              }
            });
          }
        };
        file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
        name = file.name;
        type = file.type;
        size = file.size;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        return false;
      });
    }
  };
});
app.directive("fileread", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            fileread: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.fileread = loadEvent.target.result;
                    });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

I'd like to create a custom directive like:

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFileDropzone]'
})
export class FileDropzoneDirective {

  constructor() { }

}
```

Any idea or simple link?
I'm using Angular-cli.

Comment: you are mixing angularJs with later versions of angular, which was implemented in typescript. i do not believe that you have created the project via the actual angular-cli. Just run `ng new ....` to create a project, according to https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: Actually, I ran Angular-cli, I'm noob but you can see repo :  [link] (https://github.com/BlackNeo/gedprocedures)
I'd like to use this old code I'v already wrote, but if I've to mix old and new angular, i'll find another way.. Thanks !!